# LiveData "pass-by-reference" initial value

Tags: android, kotlin, pass-by-reference, android-livedata, pass-by-value

I have a `ViewModel` class that looks like this:

```
class EditUserViewModel(
    private val initUser: User,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _user = MutableLiveData(initUser)
    val user: LiveData<User>
        get() = _user

    fun hasUserChanged() = initUser != _user.value

}
```

`User` can update some properties of the User data class instance through the UI.
To check if there are any changes when navigating from the fragment I use `hasUserChanged` method.
The problem is that is always false. I checked and it seems that the `initialUser` changes every time I change the _user `MutableLiveData`.
Why is that? Is the initial value of `MutableLiveData` passed by reference? I always thought that Kotlin is a "pass-by-value" type of language.

**Update**:
The problem seems to disappear when copying `initUser` before putting it inside the `MutableLiveData`.

```
private val _user = MutableLiveData(initUser.copy())
```

But it still doesn't make sense to me why I have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin is like java and they are pass-by-value. If you implement the `equals` function in `User` class, or make it as `data class` (which implements the `equals` function implicitly), it makes you sure that the content of the user objects is checked by `!=` operator.

**Update**

If you are changing the value of `LiveData` directly, for example like this:

```
_user.value.name = "some name"
```

it means that you are changing the `name` property of the `initUser`, because `_user.value` exactly refers to the object that the `initUser` does. Consequently, the `!=` operator always returns false, because we have one object with two references to it.

Now, when you are doing so:

```
private val _user = MutableLiveData(initUser.copy())
```

you are creating a deep copy of `initUser` (let's call it `X`) which is a new object in memory with the same property values of `initUser`.

Thus, by changing its properties like: `_user.value.name = "some name"`, in fact, you are making this change on `X`, not `initUser`. It leads to preserving the initial values in `initUser`, meaning do not changing them, and solving the issue.

Comment: The `User` class is indeed the `data class` so `hasUserChanged` method compares them correctly. But the problem is that these two compared values are the same - `initUser` is being updated every time the `_recipe` value is updated.

Comment: Ok, so if it is a data class, it doesn't mind that `!=` checks the equality of two objects with the same contents or checks an object with itself. I guess the problem is something else. Please change `hasUserChanged` like the following then check the logcat output:

```fun hasUserChanged(): Boolean {
    println("initUser: ${initUser.toString()}")
    println("_user.value: ${_user.value.toString()}")
    return initUser != _user.value
}```

Comment: I did exactly what you said and these two objects are the same, every value is the same. I also use `data binding` to update the UI using 'viewModel.recipe` in the xml file. But I don't know if that is a cause of my problem.